# Hosted Mercurial with Project Management tools

Tags: project-management, version-control, mercurial

I have used a couple of the hosted SCM's like Unfuddle and Codespaces before and I like that they have Project Management tools built in.  I've started using Mercurial and really like it, I would like to make the switch to it, but I can't seem to find any hosted mercurial solutions that contain project management tools.

Does anyone know any hosted solutions that have mercurial repositories with project management solutions?  Similar to Aseembla, CodeSpaces, Unfuddle, etc.

I know there is BitBucket, but I don't see any project management tools.

EDIT: Details about the types of tools I'm looking for.

It is for a very small team, 2-5 people.  Looking for Agile (or close to Agile) tools.  For example, in CodeSpaces there is a card wall, Assembla has a robust ticketing system that you can create swim lanes in, etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the PM tools you want. BitBucket has a basic issue tracker and wiki which I find sufficient for my solo projects. Is this for a big team? Agile? You want gantt charts or sprint planning?

Comment: @jiggy - Edited with details about tools.

Comment: I asked a similar question on Stack overflow last year, I haven't updated it in a while but some of the data there might still be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064945/42473

Comment: @Mark Booth - Thanks.  I didn't even think to ask on SO out of fear of my question being closed. :)  This is extremely helpful with some of the information.  May I ask which you chose to use and what you thought of it?

Comment: Sadly we didn't get to chose any, within a month of my bounty on that question ending my department was cut by two thirds and I was made redundant. *8'(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FogBugz (Project Management) and Kiln (Mercurial Repository). Both made by [Fog Creek](http://www.fogcreek.com). Some would say that FogBugz is only a bug tracking software but it is actually a PM tool if used correctly. There is actually a book on how to use it as a PM tool. The title of the book is Painless Project Management.

The nice thing about these two tools is that they are completed integrated so that you can tie cases to check-ins, etc.

Comment: +1 we use Fogbugz and are just starting to use Kiln.  It's rare to have tools that are so well polished.  I enjoy using them.

Comment: I evaluated all of the tools in the answers provided and really found Kiln/Fogbugz to be the biggest bang for the buck as for as a hosted solution goes.  Thanks SLoret.

Answer (score 3):

[Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) is the de facto option for hosted mercurial, the most you have for project management is a ticketing system you must enable in your repository's admin panel.

Alternatively, you could try setting up [mtrack](http://mtrack.wezfurlong.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (recommended) in your own box, both of them are full-fledged project management tools. Having your own deployment of a project management app can be the best on the long run.

Comment: I'm looking for fully hosted solutions, mainly to minimize our need for hardware (physical or virtual) for the time being. Though I will checkout mtrack and Redmine.  If the tool is good enough it might be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any bug-tracking/project-management tool I know does allow sources to be in a mercurial repository :

- http://bitbucket.org : built around Mercurial, does provide an issue system, a wiki etc. in fact all the others does too.
- http://code.google.com : does manage multiple Mercurial repostories for the same project, but is equivalent in some aspects to BitBucket (in the current implementations).
- Sourceforge : don't know much but it's an old one that was already there when mercurial wasn't born yet.
- TRAC (on your own server - python) : nice, main problem is lack of multi-projects
- Redmine (on your own server - ruby) : nice, more flexible than TRAC but have some minor youngness lacks;
- JIRA (on your own server - java) : nice, more complete than Redmine but not as flexible as TRAC - but does manage multiple projects
- Fogbugz : really nice but with a price if your project is commercial (and other conditions).
- etc.

If you don't choose one of the 3 first, then don't think about the repository type (git, mercurial, svn, whatever), the ticket management system is then more important.

If you have no clue and just want something to setup fast: if you want to have your sources available only by your team, use bitbucket. If you want to be opensource, flip a coin for bitbucket or google code.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown of the PM tools.  That is pretty helpful.