# Project Management Software / 1 maybe 2 developers

Tags: project-management, tools

I am looking for software that I can use to "manage" multiple projects (5 - 10). Here are the features I would like but any recommendation is welcome.

1. Bug/Feature tracking on a per project basis.
2. Some way to keep all documents, diagrams, specs, requirements, in one place with the project. Better yet a tool where all these things or most of them could be authored.
3. Task management during the development phase with milestones and estimates/actuals.
4. Git integration

I have been doing contract work and i have been doing really well for myself as far as getting projects but its becoming VERY hard to manage everything in an efficient manner. I am trying to learn about best practices when it comes to software programming methodologies and the more I read the more i realize that I am just managing these projects poorly. I am getting things done but the more I take on the less "solid" everything is. I am afraid if I don't get some good solid tools/practices in place I am going to do my customers and myself a disservice. The problem is that there are SO many options that its hard to weed through them all. I was at a point today where I had decided that I would just code my own (there is some irony here)!

Obviously everyone has their likes dislikes I would love to hear from some of you lone programmers and how you manage everything since our needs aren't exactly the same thing that a large team might need. I also want a solution that can scale to 2 maybe 3 developers if I end up hiring some people to help with my work load.

Thanks again for your usual insights!

Comment: May be [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) : "Trac is an open source, web-based project management and bug-tracking tool".

Comment: sounds a lot like github; though github is a bit light on milestone tracking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your requirements, and assuming you want closed-source sysetm, I would use Redmine :

- it does manage multiple projects well
- it allows to have sub-projects
- once installed, one RedMine is manageable for a ton of little projects
- it's easy to setup user access
- it's flexible, with ticket workflow (not as powerful as TRAC's one but TRAC doesn't allow multiple projects yet)

I'm using a Redmine for my little closed-source projects. I also use TRAC for a big project (that I've installed far before I learned about Redmine). I've also used bitbucket.com and code.google.com. So this advice is specific to the case you describe. In some other cases, I might have adivised another tool. If you want more infos, [see this anwser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78807/hosted-mercurial-with-project-management-tools/78887#78887), remove Google code from the list and replace bitbucket by github.com. Also, if you don't like Redmine being in ruby(-on-rails), maybe Jira will please you, as it's in Java and is, as far as I've used it at some dayjobs, equivalent.

Comment: +1 Redmine is a great tool and there is even a BitNami stack for it if you want to bring it up quickly and try it.  the level of customization and control lets you scale to multiple projects easily.  The only thing I'm not sure about is the "Git Integration" requirement

Comment: As TRAC, Jira and a lot of other, the repository type is only dependant on a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I just got JIRA & Confluence installed at my company and like both of them quite a bit. As mentioned above it's Java-based as opposed to Redmine, which is RoR.

While Redmine is Open Source, JIRA & Confluence are both commercial. Not sure how much you care about free as in speech, but JIRA & Confluence are only $10 apiece if you install on your own server and stay below 10 active users for each.

Confluence and JIRA are separate apps with a great deal of integration, but they're not really part of the same site as is Redmine's wiki. Can't comment on Redmine's wiki/issue/feature tracking integration, but I've been very happy with JIRA/Confluence integration. As an example, a wiki page with planned features and action items can be used to quickly create issues for each whose status is then communicated on the wiki page. I will also say that Confluence's wiki is quite a bit more full-featured than is Redmine's.

JIRA is really great to use for bug tracking and handles release versions and can handle Agile development with Greenhopper. There is no disputing that it is quite ugly and isn't as easy to use for release planning and project management as are Redmine or Pivotal Tracker.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Trac, Bugzilla, Redmine, and a few others, and we have settled on Redmine.  It fits our needs, is customizable enough to not back us into a corner with workflow, and easy to use (easy enough the boss gets it).  It can handle multiple projects as well as subprojects of a project.  I recommend Redmine to others.

Comment: Care to elaborate how it fitted your needs? It might not suit everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Having everything in one tool seems a bit tricky.

Why not use Jira to track bugs and a dedicated tool for managing and scheduling activities?
You can take a look at http://www.onepmo.com that comes with a scheduling engine; it means that it automatically solves resource conflicts and calculates everything for you.

Comment: Thanks for posting your first answer.  Your account id, picture and reputation score are displayed, and on Stack Exchange, adding a signature at the end of your post is discouraged.  Otherwise, great answer.  Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zoho online office productivity suite for documents etc.  SVN or GIT is just fine.  You may not get an all in one package for free, but if you can get some dough out, BaseCamp is good.

Answer (score 0):

Team Task Manager works well for us. It is intuitive and all the data is stored on your own PC instead of online.  Inexpensive, and a free trial is available on their website -  http://www.deskshare.com/team-task-management.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft Project Professional 2010. It has helped me meet crucial deadlines and select the right resources. This online [Project Management Software](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/default.aspx) delivers collaborative project management across groups of all sizes.

Comment: Could you give more details about the new and intuitive experiences ? Could you link features of your proposition to the OP requested features (How you would manage bugs and documents for example )? This would greatly improve your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Fossil is the way to go.  It provides DVCS, bug tracking and wiki in a single tool.  It has really been a productivity booster for us.